# Can't save report to different workspace - saveAsTriggered not firing in powerbi embedded

Tags: event-handling, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to create a new report in power bi embedded and save the report to a workspace that is DIFFERENT from the dataset its using I am setting up the embed token correctly - using the V2 token requests for both the dataset and workspaces but click the SaveAs in the embedded UI returns an "unable to save report" failure.

I believe what's missing is that I need to set the targetWorkspace in the SaveAs parameter. To do that I need to watch the saveAsTriggered event and in there specify the targetWorkspaceId.

However the saveAsTriggered event is never firing! Even in power bi playground the event does not seem to be firing - see code example below.

I am assuming that the saveAsTriggered event should fire even when using the embedded "Save As" button and not only if I call saveAs via the API?

In any case the event is never firing and I have no way to set the target workspace for the report to save As.

If anyone can advise another way to specify the target workspace when setting up a custom saveAs OR a way to get the saveAsTriggered event to fire, it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

I used the code below in power bi playground: https://playground.powerbi.com/en-us/dev-sandbox

```
// Embed a Power BI report in the given HTML element with the given configurations
// Read more about how to embed a Power BI report in your application here: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2153590
function embedPowerBIReport() {
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Don't change these values here: access token, embed URL and report ID. |
| To make changes to these values: |
| 1. Save any other code changes to a text editor, as these will be lost. |
| 2. Select 'Start over' from the ribbon. |
| 3. Select a report or use an embed token. |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
// Read embed application token
let accessToken = EMBED_ACCESS_TOKEN;

// Read embed URL
let embedUrl = EMBED_URL;

// Read report Id
let embedReportId = REPORT_ID;

// Read embed type from radio
let tokenType = TOKEN_TYPE;

// We give All permissions to demonstrate switching between View and Edit mode and saving report.
let permissions = models.Permissions.All;

// Create the embed configuration object for the report
// For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2153590
let config = {
type: 'report',
tokenType: tokenType == '0' ? models.TokenType.Aad : models.TokenType.Embed,
accessToken: accessToken,
embedUrl: embedUrl,
id: embedReportId,
permissions: permissions,
settings: {
panes: {
filters: {
visible: true
},
pageNavigation: {
visible: true
}
}
}
};

// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
let embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

// Embed the report and display it within the div container.
report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

// report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
report.off("loaded");

// report.on will add an event handler
report.on("loaded", function () {
loadedResolve();
report.off("loaded");
});

// report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
report.off("error");

report.on("error", function (event) {
console.log(event.detail);
});

// report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
report.off("rendered");

// report.on will add an event handler
report.on("rendered", function () {
renderedResolve();
report.off("rendered");
});
}

embedPowerBIReport();
await reportLoaded;

// Insert here the code you want to run after the report is loaded

await reportRendered;

// Switch to edit mode.
report.switchMode("edit");

// Insert here the code you want to run after the report is rendered
// report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
report.off("saveAsTriggered");

// report.on will add an event listener.
report.on("saveAsTriggered", function (event) {
console.log(event);
});

// Select Run and then select SaveAs.
// You should see an entry in the Log window.

console.log("Select SaveAs to see events in Log window.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I needed to modify the embed config to include
settings: {
useCustomSaveAsDialog: true
}

Then you do need to use your own Save As Modal but then at least the saveAsTriggered will fire!